# Return lines with at least n consecutive occurrences of the pattern in bash

Tags: awk, grep

Might be naive question, but I can't find an answer.
Given a text file, I'd like to find lines with at least (defined number) of occurrences of a certain pattern, say, AT[GA]CT.

For example, in n=2, from the file:

**ATGCT**TTGA

TAG**ATGCTATACT**TGA

TAG**ATGCT**GT**ATACT**TGA

Only the second line should be returned.

I know how to use grep/awk to search for at least one instance of this degenerate pattern, and for some defined number of pattern instances occurring non-consecutively. But the issue is the pattern occurrences MUST be consecutive, and I can't figure out how to achieve that.

Any help appreciated, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `grep -E '(AT[GA]CT){2}' input.txt`

Comment: The suggested duplicate is for Javascript but it certainly should work for Awk and `grep -E` too.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I posted thanks response here before, don't know where did it go. This worked. I realized I was not using option "-E" that's why was struggling

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
ATGCTTTGA
TAGATGCTATACTTGA
TAGATGCTGTATACTTGA
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{p="AT[GA]CT";n=2;for(i=1;i<=2;i+=1){pat=pat p}}$0~pat' file.txt
```

output

```
TAGATGCTATACTTGA
```

Explanation: I use `for` loop to repeat `p` `n` times, then filter line by checking if line (`$0`) does match with what I created earlier.

Alternatively you might use string formatting function `sprintf` as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=2}$0~sprintf("(AT[GA]CT){%s}",n)' file.txt
```

Explanation: I used [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, `%s` in first argument marks where to put `n`. If you want to know more about what might be used in `printf` and `sprintf` first argument read [Format Modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html)

*(both solutions tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: This is hugely overcomplicated. Just `grep -E "(AT[GA]CT){$n}" file` if you really insist on getting the repeat count from a variable. But I see no indication that this is actually a requirement.